# Adding Screen Before Splash

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, macos

Can i add some images(3) on scroll view to flip them as page controller and include them with the splash, so that they only appear when someone install's the application or when newer version is installed... is their a way of doing it programmatically instead of adding xib .. any help ... coding will be much appreciated  .. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant show them along with the Default launch image. You can only show a static image there. But when the user is using the app for the first time, you can show this particular view once the app is launched and then from second time onwards you can disable it. You can set a property in `NSUserDefaults` for this once you have shown this view to the user so that from second time onwards, user wont see it again.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *string = [defaults objectForKey:@"didShowCustomView"];

if ([string isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
  //show the custom view

  //once it is shown, set the value in user defaults
  [defaults setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"didShowCustomView"]; 
  [defaults synchronize];
}
```

Comment: It can be done in a lot of ways. You can create `UIScrollView` and add `UIImageViews` on top of that. You may have to enable paging on scrollview. If you are new to iOS development, I would suggest you to go through ray wenderlich tutorials, http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

Comment: Thank you very much .. i'll follow them

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me as NSUserDefault really did the [trick](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MzUPldHsodI) ..

But i had to put the loop in reverse for working it out in my very first view controller i did like this ...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad  {

 NSString *type = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myText1"];

if([type isEqualToString:@"Kill"]) {

 // put the method of view like images,buttons or anything you have in your method
 // for loading on to the first view that you want to run after splash

}

if(!type) {
    type = @"Kill";
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:type forKey:@"myText1"];

    // put the code for your splash image here .. 

         }

 }
```

So now the splash will only run once the app get's installed as a fresh copy ..
This one Helped me out ... if any one looking for the same thing can try my code above ..
Thank you